How to query a tree structure and sort children in mongodb
I want to query the entire tree structure in mongodb, and I found a piece of code here.
aggregations shell.
[
  {
    $match: { pid: 0 }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "administrative_divisions",
      startWith: "$_id",
      connectFromField: "_id",
      connectToField: "pid",
      depthField: "level",
      as: "children"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$children",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }, 
  {
    $sort: {
      "children.level": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      path: {
        $first: "$path"
      },
      pid: {
        $first: "$pid"
      },
      children: {
        $push: "$children"
      }
    }
  },  
  {
    $addFields: {
      children: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$children",
          initialValue: {
            level: -1,
            presentChild: [],
            prevChild: []
          },
          in: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                prev: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$value.level",
                        "$$this.level"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value.prevChild",
                    "$$value.presentChild"
                  ]
                },
                current: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$value.level",
                        "$$this.level"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value.presentChild",
                    []
                  ]
                }
              },
              in: {
                level: "$$this.level",
                prevChild: "$$prev",
                presentChild: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$current",
                    [
                      {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$this",
                          {
                            children: {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$$prev",
                                as: "e",
                                cond: {
                                  $eq: [
                                    "$$e.pid",
                                    "$$this._id"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      children: "$children.presentChild"
    }
  }  
]

But there is no sorting based on fields in this code.
If there is a field sort per node, Java type is BigDecimal, mongoDB type is string.
Data used for example:
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "New York State",
    "pid": 0,
    "level": 1,
    "sort": 2.00223000,
    "leaf": false,
    "path": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "New York City",
    "pid": 1,
    "level": 2,
    "sort": 2.0000000,
    "leaf": false,
    "path": "1, 2"
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "name": "The Bronx",
    "pid": 2,
    "level": 3,
    "sort": 1.0000000,
    "leaf": true,
    "path": "1, 2, 4"
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "name": "Brooklyn",
    "pid": 2,
    "level": 3,
    "sort": 4.0000000,
    "leaf": true,
    "path": "1, 2, 5"
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "name": "Manhattan",
    "pid": 2,
    "level": 3,
    "sort": 5.0000000,
    "leaf": true,
    "path": "1, 2, 6"
  },
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "name": "Queens",
    "pid": 2,
    "level": 3,
    "sort": 6.0000000,
    "leaf": true,
    "path": "1, 2, 7"
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "name": "Staten Island",
    "pid": 2,
    "level": 3,
    "sort": 12.0002220,
    "leaf": true,
    "path": "1, 2, 8"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "Albany",
    "pid": 1,
    "level": 2,
    "sort": 1.0023400,
    "leaf": true,
    "path": "1, 3"
  }
]

Nodes of the same level are sorted in ascending order according to the sort number.
I expect the final result:
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "New York State",
  "path": "1",
  "pid": 0,
  "children": [
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "Albany",
      "pid": 1,
      "level": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
      },
      "sort": 1.00234,
      "leaf": true,
      "path": "1, 3",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "New York City",
      "pid": 1,
      "level": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
      },
      "sort": 2,
      "leaf": false,
      "path": "1, 2",
      "children": [
        {
          "_id": 4,
          "name": "The Bronx",
          "pid": 2,
          "level": {
            "$numberLong": "1"
          },
          "sort": 1,
          "leaf": true,
          "path": "1, 2, 4",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "_id": 5,
          "name": "Brooklyn",
          "pid": 2,
          "level": {
            "$numberLong": "1"
          },
          "sort": 4,
          "leaf": true,
          "path": "1, 2, 5",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "_id": 6,
          "name": "Manhattan",
          "pid": 2,
          "level": {
            "$numberLong": "1"
          },
          "sort": 5,
          "leaf": true,
          "path": "1, 2, 6",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "_id": 7,
          "name": "Queens",
          "pid": 2,
          "level": {
            "$numberLong": "1"
          },
          "sort": 6,
          "leaf": true,
          "path": "1, 2, 7",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "_id": 8,
          "name": "Staten Island",
          "pid": 2,
          "level": {
            "$numberLong": "1"
          },
          "sort": 12.000222,
          "leaf": true,
          "path": "1, 2, 8",
          "children": []
        }
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}

How should I get the query results to sort based on the sort field?

Reference, not necessarily correct, because of the switched data.
I tried replacing { $sort: { "children.level": -1 } } with { $sort: { "children.sort": 1 } }, which broke the final result.
Adding { $sort: { "children.sort": 1 } } or { $sort: { "sort": 1 } } to the final pipe doesn't work either.


Usually you don't need $unwind, $sort, $group. You should get the same with simple children: { $first: { $sortArray: { input: "$children", sortBy: { level: -1 } } } }

Please provide sample input document and desired result

@WernfriedDomscheit I've added the code.

I think you just need to add 1 more level of sorting at children.sort: 1 after children.level in the $sort stage.
db.administrative_divisions.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      pid: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "administrative_divisions",
      startWith: "$_id",
      connectFromField: "_id",
      connectToField: "pid",
      depthField: "level",
      as: "children"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$children",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "children.level": -1,
      "children.sort": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      path: {
        $first: "$path"
      },
      pid: {
        $first: "$pid"
      },
      children: {
        $push: "$children"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      children: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$children",
          initialValue: {
            level: -1,
            presentChild: [],
            prevChild: []
          },
          "in": {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                prev: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$value.level",
                        "$$this.level"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value.prevChild",
                    "$$value.presentChild"
                  ]
                },
                current: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$value.level",
                        "$$this.level"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$value.presentChild",
                    []
                  ]
                }
              },
              "in": {
                level: "$$this.level",
                prevChild: "$$prev",
                presentChild: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$current",
                    [
                      {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$this",
                          {
                            children: {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$$prev",
                                as: "e",
                                cond: {
                                  $eq: [
                                    "$$e.pid",
                                    "$$this._id"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      children: "$children.presentChild"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

I have used ORM before without properly converting BigDecimal to Decimal128 causing the sorting to not work. Now, sorting works.
